# Using RichEditDocumentServer to change from rtf to text

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert RTF to plain text in a c# program. I figured out how to do it but it isn't very clean. It uses RichTextBox which I'm not a huge fan of:

```
using (System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtfBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox())
{
     rtfBox.Rtf = cTrans.NoteDescription;
     tItem.ProcedureShortDescription = rtfBox.Text;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to go about accomplishing this. Perhaps using RichEditDocumentServer? I could not find a ton of info on it though and was wondering if I could get some help on it. My thought was:

```
var documentServer = new RichEditDocumentServer();
documentServer.Document.RtfText = cTrans.NoteDescription;
tItem.ProcedureShortDescription = documentServer.Document.Text;
```

I did some more digging and this works. I figured I'd just post this as I couldn't see it answered anywhere on the site. I'm not sure if that is proper protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting it in a helper class so it can be called if needed again:

```
namespace ABELSoft.Dental.Interface.Helper
{
    public class RtfToText
    {
        public static string convert(string rtfText)
        {
            string _text;
            var documentServer = new RichEditDocumentServer();
            documentServer.Document.RtfText = rtfText;
            _text = documentServer.Document.Text;
            return _text;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I called it:

```
tItem.ProcedureShortDescription = RtfToText.convert(cTrans.NoteDescription);
```